# How to solve for loop when excuting below query

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pyspark, azure-databricks

when Country Code match with NZ it not executing IF part it always executing else part
please suggest what is the wrong in this code

```
for CountryCode in SalesOrg_RunDate_df:

    if CountryCode =='NZ':
        print(dbutils.notebook.exit(source+' Baseline '+tar))
    else:
        print('No')
```

result : NO

Comment: What is the schema of `SalesOrg_RunDate_df`?

Comment: i created data frame and we taking  max rundate and country code data from source

Answer (score 0):

insert df['CountryCode']:

```
if df['CountryCode'] =='NZ': 
      print(dbutils.notebook.exit(source+' Baseline '+tar))
else: 
    print('No')
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that you are using would compare column names to `NZ`. Since you are using pandas Dataframe, you can the following code:

- Lets say I have the following code in my dataframe:

[image]

```
for cnt in pdf['country']:
    if(cnt=='NZ'):
        print(f'this is {cnt}')
    else:
        print("NO")
```

- The following is how the output would be:

[image]